# Showing that $\int^+fd\mu = 0$ for non-negative measurable $f$ if $\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega\mid f(\omega) > 0\}) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

One of my problems ask to show that for non-negative measurable $f$ if $\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega\mid f(\omega) > 0\}) = 0$, then $\int^+fd\mu = 0$ directly from the definition that $\int^+fd\mu = \sup_{\text{non-negative simple }h, 0 \leq h \leq f}\int^\square hd\mu = \sup_{\text{non-negative simple }h, 0 \leq h \leq f} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(A_i)$, where $h = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(A_i)$ for non-negative values $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and measurable $A_1,\dots,A_n$. This might be nitpicking to myself, but IMO my current attempt doesn't prove the claim as rigorously as it could from the definition. My steps are essentially 1.) suppose $h$ is the non-negative simple function in the supremum 2.) let $(A_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a disjoint cover for the set $\{\omega \in \Omega\mid f(\omega) > 0\}$ 3.) take the maximum of the elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$, estimate upwards and conclude that $0 \leq \int^+ fd\mu \leq 0$, so that $\leq \int^+ fd\mu = 0$.

So I am interested in hearing whether there is some alternative slick way to prove the claim. So far my reading material has developed the bare minimum of measure and integration theory, so in principle most of the known tools besides the definition of a measure and monotone convergence theorem are available.

Comment: @Surb $\int^+f$ w.r.t. a measure $\mu$ is defined to be equal to  $\int^+fd\mu = \sup_{\text{non-negative simple }h, 0 \leq h \leq f}\int^\square hd\mu = \sup_{\text{non-negative simple }h, 0 \leq h \leq f} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(A_i)$

Comment: I guess that the supremum is rather taken on $h$ non negative simple s.t. $0\leq h\leq f^+$ ? (otherwise it makes no sense...) Just take $(h_n)$ simple s.t. $$\int h_n-\frac{1}{n}\leq \int ^+f\leq \int h_n,$$ and $0\leq h_n\leq f^+$. Obviously, $h_n=0$ $\mu-$a.e. (because $f\leq 0$ $\mu-$a.e.) and thus $\int h_n=0$ for all $n$. Therefore, taking $n\to \infty $ gives the wished result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is nonnegative measurable, we can find an increasing sequence of simple functions $f_n$ s.t. $f_n \uparrow f$. In particular, we can find the classic sequence $f_n^*$ s.t.
$$\int fd\mu=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int f^*_nd\mu=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{0\leq k\leq n2^n}k2^{-n}\mu(A_{n,k})$$
where $A_{n,k}=\{x:k2^{-n}\leq f(x)< (k+1)2^{-n}\}$ for $0\leq k < n2^n$ and $A_{n,n2^n}=\{x:f(x)\geq n\}$. However, $\mu(A_{n,k})=0,\,\forall n,\forall k>0$ so we are left with
$$\int fd\mu=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0\cdot \mu(A_{n,0}))=0$$